# Bokeh toggle lasso/hover

Tags: javascript, python, html, callback, bokeh

I have a lasso and a hover tool in bokeh, each with a similar callback to interact with a secondary plot (the hover will display meta data associated with a single data point, while the lasso will display the same meta data averaged across points).

The callbacks work individually for hover and for lasso, but when both are active, the hover dominates. I'd like to make is so that the user can choose either lasso or hover but not both.

Is there a way to trigger a callback when the active tool is changed, preferably in CustomJS so I don't have to run bokeh server?

Below is some sample code and [here is a link](https://leggitta.github.io/toggle_lasso_hover.html) to the output.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.layouts import row 
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import (
    ColumnDataSource, CustomJS,
    HoverTool, LassoSelectTool)

output_file('toggle_lasso_hover.html')

s1 = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': [0, 1, 2], 
    'y': [1, 1, 1]
})
s2 = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': [], 
    'y': []
})
js_args = {'s1': s1, 's2': s2} 
js_code = """ 
    var d1 = s1.data;
    var d2 = {'x': [], 'y': []};

    for (i=0; i < inds.length; i++) {
        j = inds[i];
        d2['x'].push(d1['x'][j]);
        d2['y'].push(d1['y'][j]);
    }
    s2.data = d2;
    s2.change.emit();
"""
on_hover = CustomJS(args=js_args, code="""
    var inds = cb_data.index['1d'].indices;
    %s
""" % js_code)
on_lasso = CustomJS(args=js_args, code="""
    var inds = cb_obj.selected['1d'].indices;
    %s
""" % js_code)

p1 = figure(
    width=300, height=300, tools="reset", active_drag=None)
p1.circle('x', 'y', source=s1, size=20, color='blue')

# define tools
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=on_hover)
lasso = LassoSelectTool()

p1.add_tools(hover)
p1.add_tools(lasso)
s1.callback = on_lasso

p2 = figure(
    width=300, height=300, x_range=p1.x_range, y_range=p1.y_range,
    toolbar_location=None)
p2.circle('x', 'y', source=s2, size=20, color='green')

lout = row(p1, p2) 
show(lout)
```